# no appropriate default constructor available error

Tags: c++, inheritance

here is my code:

```
class package
{
protected:
    string name;
    string city;
    string state;
    int zip;
    double weight;
    double costPerOunce;

public:

    package::package(string Name, string City, string State, int Zip, double Weight, double CostPerOunce):
      name(Name), city(City), state(State),
      zip(Zip), weight(Weight), costPerOunce(CostPerOunce)
      {

      }
      double calculateCost()
    {
        return (weight * costPerOunce);
    }

};
class twoDayPackage: public package
{
protected:
    double flatFee;
public:
    twoDayPackage::twoDayPackage(double FlatFee):
      flatFee(FlatFee)
      {

      }
    double calculateCost()
    {
        return (weight * costPerOunce) + flatFee;

    }
};
int main()
{


    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

i try to run this code and the error i get is as follows:
 error C2512: 'package' : no appropriate default constructor available

the error has something to do with inheritance of the base class constructor but i don't know exactly why the code isn't running. please help me.

Comment: please learn the basic syntax...

Comment: When you write your own constructor, the default one will be overridden. `twoDayPackage::twoDayPackage(double FlatFee):` will call it, but it doesn't exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor for `twoDayPackage` will first create `package`, before constructing `flatFee`. As you don't tell it how to do that, it looks for a default way of constructing `package`.

When you construct `twoDayPackage` you need to give it everything it needs to construct the underlying `package`. Either that, or have it determine values to pass to the `package` constructor.

Passing in the required parameters looks like this:

```
class twoDayPackage {
public:
    twoDayPackage(string Name, string City, string State, int Zip, double Weight, double CostPerOunce, double flatFee) :
    package(Name, City, State, Zip, Weight, CostPerOunce),
    flatFee(flatFee) {
    }
    //..
};
```

Comment: what is the syntax for what you are suggesting?

Comment: you my friend, are a true ninja. thank you very much. My code is now running exactly how i wanted it to. Again, Muchos Gracias!!!

Answer (score 4):

```
twoDayPackage::twoDayPackage(double FlatFee):
  flatFee(FlatFee)
```

is calling the base constructor `package()`, because you haven't specified anything else.

Add a line `package::package(){};` in class package :)

Comment: +1, but a default constructor means he'd not be initializing any of those other members (weight, etc...). But yeah - that's probably beyond the scope of this question :)

Comment: Moo-Juice - yeah, a short answer not a complete answer.  I find solving one problem at a time helps when trying to learn c++ syntax.

Comment: Well, the three `string` ones would be.

Comment: This doesn't tell OP the dangers though.

Comment: i have added the line and the program runs. now i want to make the class twoDayPackage take values of the class package. please help.

Comment: @user2361090, it's not clear to me what you want.  PeterWood 's answer shows how to implement and call a useful base class constructor.

Comment: @Melanie I read Peter Wood's answer and what do you know, it worked as i wanted it to... thank you for the concern. highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need a constructor for package.
Also you don't need the `package::package(...)` when declaring the constructor ( that's for when you define it in the cpp file. ) Just `package(...)` will be just fine.

```
class package
{
protected:
    string name;
    string city;
    string state;
    int zip;
    double weight;
    double costPerOunce;

public:
    package()
    {}
    // \/ You don't need package:: that's only needed when you define the func in cpp
    package(
        string Name, string City, string State, int Zip, 
        double Weight, double CostPerOunce
    )
        : name(Name), city(City), state(State),
        zip(Zip), weight(Weight), costPerOunce(CostPerOunce)
    {

    }
    double calculateCost()
    {
        return (weight * costPerOunce);
    }

};
```